# Google Login - 401 error "Login Required" when trying to access userinfo

Tags: android, node.js, authentication, google-authentication

I have an Android app that supports Login with Google using `PlusClient`. After I connect, I get the auth token using an `AsyncTask` and the `GoogleAuthUtil.getToken` method as follows:

> private void fetchAuthToken() {
>           AsyncTask task = new AsyncTask() {

```
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String token = null;
            String scope = "oauth2: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email";//"oauth2: "+ Scopes.PLUS_PROFILE;
            Bundle appActivities = new Bundle();
            appActivities.putString(GoogleAuthUtil.KEY_REQUEST_VISIBLE_ACTIVITIES, visiblaeActivities);
            try {                   
                token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Login.instance.context, mPlusClient.getAccountName(), scope, appActivities);
            } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {                  
                loginActivity.startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUSET_TOKEN_PERMISSIONS_RESLOVE_ERR);                 
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return token;
        }
```

This works great, and then I send the token to my backend which is in node.js, there, I try to fetch the user details from google using this request:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo?access_token=' + access_token
```

and then I get the user's details and everything is Hunky Dory. The problem is, sometimes I get this error that the token is not valid, which looks like this:

> "error": {
>      "errors": [
>       {
>        "domain": "global",
>        "reason": "required",
>        "message": "Login Required",
>        "locationType": "header",
>        "location": "Authorization"
>       }
>      ],
>      "code": 401,
>      "message": "Login Required"
>     }
>    }

And my guess is someone tries to login with google but can't connect for some reason. this is hard to debug because it happens sporadically, and most users login successfully. Anyone?

**P.S**
I only fetch the token after the user is connected, i.e. - I call `fetchAuthToken()` within the `onConnected` callback, so the user is definitely logged in by then

Answer (score 0):

My idea: are you keeping your session info? Your http client needs to keep track of the session otherwise the token might become invalid.

```
BasicCookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
```

and then add context to your post/get/whatever request you are making

```
client.execute(post, localContext);
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean by keeping my session info. I'm using loopj's `PersistentCookieStore` for every request, so all the cookies are sent with the request to the server.

Comment: It would be helpful, Chris, if you could clarify what you mean by keeping session info. Additionally, Evan, if you've solved this, you could post your own answer, which would be extremely helpful to others facing this or a similar problem.

Comment: @jmort253 , This just stopped happening at some point, I'm chalking this one up to Google.. you can try to use an older API version like: `https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/people/me?access_token=...` which also might work

Comment: @OferM, okay, hate going backwards as you then have to deal with deprecation policies... but I'll keep this in mind. Thanks!